# regex that matches a literal that doesn't have another literal before it

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

So I had a requirement where I wanted to replace all the `=` from a string with `==` but the problem was that string may contain `!=` as well and I don't want `=` or `!=` to be replaced.
So just replacing `=` with `==` won't work, I was thinking if there is a way where I can check if the `=` doesn't have `!` before it then replaces.
I looked for look around regex but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Read about [look-behinds](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html).

Comment: Your Sample I/O?

Comment: If you just want to replace `==`, then what would be wrong with just replacing two equals in succession?

Comment: duplicate question.

Comment: `(?<!!)=` Should get you the equals that are not preceded by `!`

Answer (score 0):

Using [replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm):

```
test = "Hey this is a == test where != or = should not be changed"
print(test.replace("==", "="))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Hey this is a = test where != or = should not be changed
```

OR

```
import re
replaced = re.sub('==', '=', test)
print(replaced)
```

EDIT:

What you need is:

[`(?<!a)b matches a "b" that is not preceded by an "a",`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Regex for `=` where `=` is not preceded by an `=`:

```
test = "Hey this is a = test where != or = should not be changed"

import re
print(re.findall(r'(?<!!)=', test))
```

Comment: Edited my answer for the fix, downvoter might want to remove his downvote now?